How to Display AdMob Adaptive Banner Above the Bottom UI Navigation Bar in Unity?
Image-1
Hello,
I am currently using AdMob banner ads in Unity, and what I want to do now is position the banner above the UI navigation bar, as shown in the image. However, the positioning seems to vary across different phone sizes.
private float ConvertPixelsToDP(float pixels)
{
    return pixels / (Screen.dpi / 160);
}

private int ConvertPixelsToDeviceScale(float pixels)
{
    return Mathf.RoundToInt(pixels / MobileAds.Utils.GetDeviceScale());
}

1-)
bannerView.SetPosition(0, ConvertPixelsToDP(ConvertPixelsToDeviceScale(Screen.height - offsetY - bannerView.GetHeightInPixels())));

This method works for some phones, but it doesn't work correctly on all devices.
2-)
bannerView.SetPosition(0, ConvertPixelsToDP(ConvertPixelsToDeviceScale(Screen.height - offsetY - safeAreaTopPadding - bannerView.GetHeightInPixels())));

Here, I tried to account for the safe area by subtracting safeAreaTopPadding to handle devices with notches or different safe area sizes, but this still doesn't work correctly.
3-) I also tried replacing the ConvertPixelsToDP() method with ConvertPixelsToDeviceScale() method as I’ve seen posts suggesting that Unity might be miscalculating for banner ads in certain cases.
Extra Information:
bannerView.SetPosition(0, 0);

When I set the y value to 0, the banner automatically uses the safe area for positioning.
Could anyone explain how bannerView.SetPosition() calculates the position? Or suggest a method to correctly place the AdMob banner above the UI navigation bar on different devices?

Try the following method, it will surely help.
private void SetBannerPositionAboveNavigationBar()
{
    Rect safeArea = Screen.safeArea;
    float bannerHeightPx = 50f * Screen.dpi / 160f; // Assuming 50dp
    float customY = safeArea.yMin + bannerHeightPx;
    bannerView.SetPosition((int)(Screen.width / 2), (int)customY);
}


Thank you for your response. However, the issue is not about displaying a banner above the safeArea.
For this, using bannerView.SetPosition(BannerPosition.Bottom); should be sufficient. Also, I forgot to mention that I am using an adaptive banner, so the height may change. I can retrieve the height dynamically with the code bannerView.GetHeightInPixels(); instead of using a static value.
If you were referring to something different, could you please clarify in more detail?

then your question shouldnt be so much about the position.. as it reads, it seems utterly about position

Yes, my issue is completely related to the position, but I want to place the banner above specifically above the navigation bar I created in the UI. Just like in the image I attached. The problem is that when calculating the position, as I mentioned earlier, it doesn't give the same result on every DPI. On some devices, the banner is positioned higher, while on others it's placed lower.
